# Windows Service stopped reading messages from Azure service bus

Tags: .net, windows-services, azureservicebus

I have a windows service running on Windows server 2012, that reads messages from azure service bus (subscription) and processes the message. Recently, the windows service stopped reading any messages. It would start reading messages if the service is restarted. And would continue processing messages, until it stops reading messages again(*idle?*).

There have been no failures, no exceptions thrown by the service.

Uses ReceiveMode.PeekLock.

nuget package: WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 3.0.8

Any ideas how to solve this issue so that service continuously reads the messages?

```
var subscriptionDescription = new SubscriptionDescription("test TopicPath, "my SubscriptionName")
                {
                    LockDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 180),
                    MaxDeliveryCount = 2
                };
```

...
Create or update subscription based on subscriptionDescription
...

```
 var subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString("test ConnectionString", "test TopicPath","my SubscriptionName", ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
var onMessageOptions = new OnMessageOptions
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 3,
            AutoComplete = false
        };
subscriptionClient.OnMessage(HandleMessage, onMessageOptions);
```

...
..

```
private void HandleMessage(BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)
{
    ProcessMessage(message);
    brokeredMessage.SafeComplete();
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of your service please ? At least relevant part.

Comment: @Thomas - Added the relevant code. Please let me know if that helps. I couldn't find any issues in the code as such. but, may be any updates to the configurations or how the application is set up in the server that could help with the issue?

Comment: Did you have any log on your server ? What is the nuget package version ?

Comment: @Thomas - no logs in the server against the service that indicates a warning, error or exception. nuget package , windowsazure.servicebus - 3.0.8(not the latest..)